# Are "Clean Code" practices really that clean and useful?

Tags: programming-practices, agile, clean-code

I am currently doing an internship in a large corporation and they are undergoing many changes in software delivery structure (moving to Agile).

In the past couple of months I have noticed this religious attachment to `Clean Code` practices and [the book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882)  being like a bible for the developers.

Now, one of the most important features of the clean code is self-explanatory code which is based on understandable naming and rigorous re-factoring.  This is followed by `no commenting` rule.

I understand that this clean code is a long term investment which will ease following code maintenance and improvement, but... is this really worth all this fuss?

Would anyone share their experience on Clean Code and any opinion whether I am just too conservative or it is just a temporary trend.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Yes rules like that are complete hokum which anyone who actually took time to think about critically would notice. Sure `one level of abstraction` sounds nice in theroy but in practice what is considered a level of abstraction relies too much on personal judgement or as you noticed should be ignored because it gives up too much locality

Comment: I don't have a very high opinion of that book (despite its author). In general it pays not to be too dogmatic. Most programming recommendations are because they have been shown to work in practice, but they are not the absolute truth, so don't worry too much. Keep reading and go with what you feel is more correct, but don't reinvent the wheel either. Chances are someone smarter than us has already figured out better solutions than our own.

Comment: A method with a 70 character name probably does more than one thing. SRP violation am I right?!

Comment: Here's another thought, 5 or 10 years from now when you are a developer at a company that could care less about clean code, you'll really appreciate this dogmatic exercise.

Comment: Having worked (briefly) under "no comments", I very much prefer it to be a *strong guideline* than a rule. There are times when comments are needed - usually in obscure business logic. A method called `CalculateFoonicityMetric()` tells you exactly what it's doing, and well-written code will show you how... but neither of these tell you *why*. Code can be obvious in *what* (multiply this by that, divide by the other thing, square it, add on this bit...) but unclear in *why* (factor = a*b/c; square to account for negative foo, adjust for drift...). I appreciate a quick comment that explains why.

Comment: Clean Code 101: the fundamentals (refactoring, naming, etc). Clean Code 201: SOLID principles. Clean Code 301: proper application design. thats the huge payoff. check out clean code videos: update book concepts and present a more balanced view including contradictions. So yeah its NOT about refactoring but you have to learn the difference between a function and a class and why its important. after you have learned proper application design you will spend much less time refactoring.

Comment: there are also many free videos of the author robert martin giving lectures that go into the larger concerns beyond refactoring etc. From NDC 2013 "Principles of Component Design" http://vimeo.com/68236438 "Clean Architecture and Design" http://vimeo.com/68215570  Lots on skillsmatter.com  Systems and Domains:  http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/agile-testing/uncle-bob

Comment: i tried to edit this question so it would pass. the no comment 'rule' is not a rule! its to illustrate the tendency of making method names hard to understand - and then justifying it by long comments. **the real point or goal is to make your method names so descriptive and accurate that the comments are not needed.** but obviously you can still use comments especially if its a part of your IDE or documentation practices.

Comment: Clean code sure can reduce a lot of unnecessary code noise, which makes things much faster and easier to read at times.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I understand that this clean code is a long term investment which will ease following code maintenance and improvement, but... is this really worth all this fuss?

Absolutely.

> Re-factoring is very important, but spending 75% of your time moving the methods and spending loads of time to decide its proper title does not seem to be that productive.

Sure, but consider that the large company probably has years or decades of bad code to clean up. It's going to take a lot of time and effort to do that.

The main thing to realize is that you're both right. "clean code" is very important, and Clean Code is a universally respected way to get there. Since the company has just started along the path, they're going to be beholden to the book more than a group that has more experience. Once they've done it for a short while, they'll begin to learn what works and what doesn't. Once they understand that better, they'll (hopefully) follow a more pragmatic  and natural approach that maintains clean code, but doesn't lead to 70 char function names.

Answer (score 4):

I was originally writing a comment.  I'll try to give less of an answer than perspectives to consider.  However, I absolutely endorse "Clean Code" practices like understandable naming and refactoring.

I've always disliked the **no comments** rules, as there are cases where comments are necessary to prevent future code breakage.  They normally should be restricted to what is being done and why.  Use them sparingly when the code is doing something unexpected, or an algorithm needed to be replaced.

Consider productivity when you are reading or maintaining code.  In the lifetime of the code, this may be more important than productivity when writing the code.  Will these practices help productivity in these tasks?

With experience, these practices should become ingrained, and less of a productivity killer.  Choosing the right name may take longer because you are clarifying what the code needs to do.  (This clarification may make coding and debugging go faster.) Does this result in code that does only what is require or that has less bugs?  What effect does this have on productivity?

The time taken in choosing the right method name will likely pay off immediately in better understanding what the method's purpose is.  Compare the method names "iterateOverCustomers" to "locateActiveCustomers".  Which one conveys the intent of the function?  Which one will be easier to refactor if necessary?

Comment: I'd like to point out that the "no comments" rule that people like to attribute to the Clean Code book is not actually anywhere in the book. On the contrary, there's an entire chapter on comments, the first half of which is spent describing many types of "good comments", followed by the section on "bad comments". The author's opinions on the matter are actually much more reasonable than many give him credit for.

Comment: I was commenting on "no comments" rules in general.  I have worked in languages where there have been proposals to remove comments from the language definition.  No comments good or bad.  At the time we had a comment in a block of code where it was desirable to fall through in some cases.  There was a comment warning that such was the case and not to add new blocks of code at that point.

Comment: Yeah, that seems pretty extreme to me.